# why does coffeescript print to the console by default, and how to disable this?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Why does this code print the entire loop to the coffeescript console if i don't console.log explicitly?

```
multiples = (num * 10 for num in [0..1000])
```

how can i disable this behavior?

in Python this works without printing anything

```
multiples = [x*10 for x in range(1000)]
```

Comment: The CoffeeScript REPL just a thin wrapper around node.js's REPL so that's actually node's REPL printing the result of the last expression. In your case, the last expression is the `multiples = ...` assignment so you see the whole content of `multiples`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add return true at the end.